# Mysql Error I can't find/may not exist

Tags: mysql

```
 $query = "
        INSERT INTO rets_property_res (ACREAGE, BATHS_FULL, BATHS_HALF, BEDROOMS, CATEGORY, CITY, COUNTY, CO_LA_CODE, CO_LO_CODE, CURRENT_PRICE, DATE_MODIFIED, DIRECTIONS, ELEM_SCHOOL, FTR_APPLIANCE, FTR_CONSTRC_STATUS, FTR_CONSTRUC, FTR_COOLING, FTR_DESIGN, FTR_DININGTYPE, FTR_ENERGY, FTR_EXTERIOR, FTR_FACILITY, FTR_FLOORS, FTR_HEATING, FTR_INTERIOR, FTR_INTERNET, FTR_LOTDESC, FTR_MSTR_BATH_DESC, FTR_MSTR_BDRM_DESC, FTR_PARKING, FTR_POOL, FTR_ROOF, FTR_SIDING, FTR_SPECIAL_SALE_TYPE, FTR_STYLE, FTR_WATERFRONT, FTR_WATERVIEW, HIGH_SCHOOL, INTERMEDIATE_SCHOOL, LA_CODE, LIST_DATE, LIST_PRICE, LOT_DIMENSIONS, LO_CODE, MEDIA_FLAG, MIDDLE_SCHOOL, MLS_ACCT, PHOTO_COUNT, PHOTO_DATE_MODIFIED, PROJ_NAME, PROP_TYPE, REMARKS, STATE, STATUS, STREET_DIR, STREET_NAME, STREET_NUM, SUBDIVISION, TOT_HEAT_SQFT, UNIT_NUM, VT_YN, YEAR_BUILT, ZIP) 
        VALUES (\"$listing[ACREAGE]\", \"$listing[BATHS_FULL]\", \"$listing[BATHS_HALF]\", \"$listing[BEDROOMS]\", \"$listing[CATEGORY]\", \"$listing[CITY]\", \"$listing[COUNTY]\", \"$listing[CO_LA_CODE]\", \"$listing[CO_LO_CODE]\", \"$listing[CURRENT_PRICE]\", \"$listing[DATE_MODIFIED]\", \"$listing[DIRECTIONS]\", \"$listing[ELEM_SCHOOL]\", \"$listing[FTR_APPLIANCE]\", \"$listing[FTR_CONSTRC_STATUS]\", \"$listing[FTR_CONSTRUC]\", \"$listing[FTR_COOLING]\", \"$listing[FTR_DESIGN]\", \"$listing[FTR_DININGTYPE]\", \"$listing[FTR_ENERGY]\", \"$listing[FTR_EXTERIOR]\", \"$listing[FTR_FACILITY]\", \"$listing[FTR_FLOORS]\", \"$listing[FTR_HEATING]\", \"$listing[FTR_INTERIOR]\", \"$listing[FTR_INTERNET]\", \"$listing[FTR_LOTDESC]\", \"$listing[FTR_MSTR_BATH_DESC]\", \"$listing[FTR_MSTR_BDRM_DESC]\", \"$listing[FTR_PARKING]\", \"$listing[FTR_POOL]\", \"$listing[FTR_ROOF]\", \"$listing[FTR_SIDING]\", \"$listing[FTR_SPECIAL_SALE_TYPE]\", \"$listing[FTR_STYLE]\", \"$listing[FTR_WATERFRONT]\", \"$listing[FTR_WATERVIEW]\", \"$listing[HIGH_SCHOOL]\", \"$listing[INTERMEDIATE_SCHOOL]\", \"$listing[LA_CODE]\", \"$listing[LIST_DATE]\", \"$listing[LIST_PRICE]\", \"$listing[LOT_DIMENSIONS]\", \"$listing[LO_CODE]\", \"$listing[MEDIA_FLAG]\", \"$listing[MIDDLE_SCHOOL]\", \"$listing[MLS_ACCT]\", \"$listing[PHOTO_COUNT]\", \"$listing[PHOTO_DATE_MODIFIED]\", \"$listing[PROJ_NAME]\", \"$listing[PROP_TYPE]\", \"$listing[REMARKS]\", \"$listing[STATE]\", \"$listing[STATUS]\", \"$listing[STREET_DIR]\", \"$listing[STREET_NAME]\", \"$listing[STREET_NUM]\", \"$listing[SUBDIVISION]\", \"$listing[TOT_HEAT_SQFT]\", \"$listing[UNIT_NUM]\", \"$listing[VT_YN]\", \"$listing[YEAR_BUILT]\", \"$listing[ZIP]\")";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'television above your gas fireplace or enjoying your view of the Bay. Then open' at line 2

I can't find the error. I have been looking for like 2 hrs. What is spilled out as an "error" is from the REMARKS field. There isn't a syntax error though.

Comment: Use an `echo $query;` to find out where the problem is.

Comment: I have a feeling there is a quote in the $listing[REMARKS] variable.

Comment: is `$listing[...]` properly escaped?

Comment: So this field may be pulling text that has a " in it.  How can I pull this data out then put the " back in so the text isn't ruined. I don't control the database I am pulling from.  Thanks for your quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO rets_property_res (ACREAGE, BATHS_FULL, BATHS_HALF, BEDROOMS, CATEGORY, CITY, COUNTY, CO_LA_CODE, CO_LO_CODE, CURRENT_PRICE, DATE_MODIFIED, DIRECTIONS, ELEM_SCHOOL, FTR_APPLIANCE, FTR_CONSTRC_STATUS, FTR_CONSTRUC, FTR_COOLING, FTR_DESIGN, FTR_DININGTYPE, FTR_ENERGY, FTR_EXTERIOR, FTR_FACILITY, FTR_FLOORS, FTR_HEATING, FTR_INTERIOR, FTR_INTERNET, FTR_LOTDESC, FTR_MSTR_BATH_DESC, FTR_MSTR_BDRM_DESC, FTR_PARKING, FTR_POOL, FTR_ROOF, FTR_SIDING, FTR_SPECIAL_SALE_TYPE, FTR_STYLE, FTR_WATERFRONT, FTR_WATERVIEW, HIGH_SCHOOL, INTERMEDIATE_SCHOOL, LA_CODE, LIST_DATE, LIST_PRICE, LOT_DIMENSIONS, LO_CODE, MEDIA_FLAG, MIDDLE_SCHOOL, MLS_ACCT, PHOTO_COUNT, PHOTO_DATE_MODIFIED, PROJ_NAME, PROP_TYPE, REMARKS, STATE, STATUS, STREET_DIR, STREET_NAME, STREET_NUM, SUBDIVISION, TOT_HEAT_SQFT, UNIT_NUM, VT_YN, YEAR_BUILT, ZIP) 
    VALUES (
     '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['ACREAGE'])."', 
     '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['BATHS_FULL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['BATHS_HALF'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['BEDROOMS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['CATEGORY'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['CITY'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['COUNTY'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['CO_LA_CODE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['CO_LO_CODE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['CURRENT_PRICE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['DATE_MODIFIED'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['DIRECTIONS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['ELEM_SCHOOL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_APPLIANCE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_CONSTRC_STATUS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_CONSTRUC'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_COOLING'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_DESIGN'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_DININGTYPE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_ENERGY'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_EXTERIOR'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_FACILITY'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_FLOORS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_HEATING'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_INTERIOR'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_INTERNET'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_LOTDESC'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_MSTR_BATH_DESC'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_MSTR_BDRM_DESC'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_PARKING'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_POOL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_ROOF'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_SIDING'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_SPECIAL_SALE_TYPE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_STYLE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_WATERFRONT'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['FTR_WATERVIEW'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['HIGH_SCHOOL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['INTERMEDIATE_SCHOOL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['LA_CODE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['LIST_DATE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['LIST_PRICE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['LOT_DIMENSIONS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['LO_CODE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['MEDIA_FLAG'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['MIDDLE_SCHOOL'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['MLS_ACCT'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['PHOTO_COUNT'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['PHOTO_DATE_MODIFIED'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['PROJ_NAME'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['PROP_TYPE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['REMARKS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['STATE'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['STATUS'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['STREET_DIR'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['STREET_NAME'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['STREET_NUM'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['SUBDIVISION'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['TOT_HEAT_SQFT'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['UNIT_NUM'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['VT_YN'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['YEAR_BUILT'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($listing['ZIP'])."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Note that this is not the best way to do it and you should use MySQLi/PDO for a more secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest.. it is very hard to debug like this. There could be a chance that in REMARKS field, you have un-escaped double quote or other characters that break the query compiling. Have you tried to insert a small amount of data first?

I will suggest inserting a 'hello world' first before going crazy with this kind of insert.

I also suggest using single quote like '$listing[REMARKS]' as the default mysql syntax.

Comment: I am pulling the information from a database. I dont' know a lot about escaping data. I dont' want the data to have it's quotes removed from within it as it might make it unreadable.  Do I award people somehow for their assistance?

Comment: Are you pulling information or inserting? Because your question is to use query to insert into database. And I was suggesting using single quote to surround the value. I was not telling you to remove any quotes within the content.